# which g++ parameters should I choose when compiling dynamic link file for java?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I compiled a JNI file with g++:

```
g++ -shared -o test.so test.cpp -fPIC
```

java could not find symbol :

> com_idp_common_util_J:java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   com.idp.common.util.J

when I use "readelf" to read the dynamic link file symbol it seems to be strange:

> 0000000000000dcc   274 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11
>   _Z44com_idp_common_util_J

what does that mean "_Z44"? And what`s the right way to generate dynamic link file ?

Comment: Are you using the header file generated by `javah` ?

Comment: Is it possible for you to paste the whole exception? Maybe issue is related to shared library that is linked with your JNI library?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here for C++ based sample used from JNI:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo025

This line should be enough in case of the code. But make sure to follow strict rules of JNI naming convention

```
g++ -g -shared -fpic -I${JAVA_HOME}/include -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux source.cpp -o lib/libName.so
```

In the sample above, you will see how to generate header file that follows JNI rules:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html

Take a look at section: Resolving Native Method Names

You can easily generate it using javah tool

```
$(JAVA_HOME)/bin/javah -jni -cp target JavaClass
```

Comment: I had tried add  JDK include DIR ,but it is the same result.

Comment: This problem is resolved。It is name mangling and my extern “C” is not right used。 and another problem is my JNI Method missing “Java_”

Comment: Yeap, using javah is always the easies way to generate these nasty, weird JNI headers.